# Problems with recursive templates in D

Tags: templates, recursion, compiler-errors, metaprogramming, d

My first attempt to use recursive templates in d and i'm lost:

```
import std.stdio, std.conv, orange.util.Reflection;

struct Foo {
    int a = 7;
    int b = 4;
    int c = 5;
}

void main(string[] args) { 
    pragma(msg,dictString!Foo);
}

template ObjDict(T) {

}

template dictString (T) {
    const dictString = dictStringImpl!(T, 0);
}

template dictStringImpl (T, size_t i) {
    static if(T.tupleof.length == 0)
        const dictString = "";
    else static if(T.tupleof.length -1 == i) {
        pragma(msg, to!string("i = "~to!string(i)~" name = "~nameOfFieldAt!(T,i)));
        const dictString = "dict[\"" ~ nameOfFieldAt!(T,i) ~ "\"] = " ~ nameOfFieldAt!(T,i) ~ ";";
        pragma(msg,"last one "~to!string(i)~" \""~dictString~"\"");
    }
    else {
        pragma(msg, to!string("i = "~to!string(i)~" name = "~nameOfFieldAt!(T,i)));
        const dictString = "dict[\"" ~ nameOfFieldAt!(T,i) ~ "\"] = " ~ nameOfFieldAt!(T,i) ~ ";\n" ~ dictStringImpl!(T, i+1);
    }
}
```

which, when compiled gives:

```
i = 0 name = a
i = 1 name = b
i = 2 name = c
last one 2 "dict["c"] = c;"
orange_test.d(31): Error: void has no value
orange_test.d(31): Error: incompatible types for (("dict[\"" ~ nameOfFieldAt ~ "\"] = " ~ nameOfFieldAt ~ ";\x0a") ~ (dictStringImpl!(Foo,2LU))): 'string' and 'void'
orange_test.d(31): Error: template instance orange_test.dictStringImpl!(Foo,1LU) error instantiating
orange_test.d(18):        instantiated from here: dictStringImpl!(Foo,0)
orange_test.d(10):        instantiated from here: dictString!(Foo)
orange_test.d(18): Error: template instance orange_test.dictStringImpl!(Foo,0) error instantiating
orange_test.d(10):        instantiated from here: dictString!(Foo)
orange_test.d(10): Error: template instance orange_test.dictString!(Foo) error instantiating
orange_test.d(10):        while evaluating pragma(msg, dictString!(Foo))
```

as you can see, there's no problem with the nameOfFieldAt templates from orange, but something goes wrong in the recursion, i think.

Any help would be much appreciated, I'd love to get this working.

see here for a version with the relevant orange template (and a few others) http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/4b7a36f8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your dictStringImpl template you are still using dictString as an eponymous name :)
Was not looking further, but that will fix void related error.

Comment: well that was simple. Thanks, all fixed now :)